# How to implement Holidays and work week days in AnyChart Gantt Resource

Tags: gantt-chart, anychart

I'm trying to define the work days of the week and also the holidays in a Resource gantt but with no luck!
Any one knows how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of AnyGantt 8.2.1 doesn't support such feature. We are going to implement it, but the ETA is not assigned yet. As an alternative AnyChart provides a redesigned version of Resource chart which is a fresh look at Gantt and Resource charts. This resource chart supports such feature - availabilities. You can take a look at samples in [chart gallery](https://www.anychart.com/products/anygantt/gallery/Resource_Charts/). You can learn more about availabilities feature in [the API reference](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.scales.Calendar#availabilities)