# Anychart Gantt hiding times

Tags: anychart

I am wondering if there is any way to hide holiday days or no working days in the timeline of a Gantt chart in order to show only the real time I am interested for.

I have seen this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044455/how-to-implement-holidays-and-work-week-days-in-anychart-gantt-resource) but is 3 years old..

Is there any improvement now ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

We are glad that you’ve found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044455/how-to-implement-holidays-and-work-week-days-in-anychart-gantt-resource) comment.

Unfortunately, the hide specific days feature in AnyGantt has not yet been implemented, we are still considering it and hope to add it in the future releases.